# C# Error : Input string was not in a correct format

Tags: string, c#-4.0

I have little experience in VS and I don't really know what is wrong with my code here:

```
public static DataTable BindStudentsearchList(int FeeDate, int IsArcive)
{
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Global.getconnection());
        SqlCommand cmdnew = new SqlCommand();
        cmdnew.CommandText = "SELECT A.Studentid,A.Name,F.FeeDate,F.Fee FROM tbl_Student A inner join tbl_Fee F on A.StudentId= F.fkStudentId where FeeDate= "+ FeeDate +"  and A.IsArcive=0";
        cmdnew.Connection = cn;
        cn.Open();
        DataTable dts = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter das = new SqlDataAdapter();
        das.SelectCommand = cmdnew;
        das.Fill(dts);
        return dts;
    }            
}

public void bindUsersearchGrid()
{
    DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();
    grdFeeDetail.DataSource = BindStudentsearchList(Convert.ToInt32(txtSearch.Text), 0);
}

private void btnDailyFee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bindUsersearchGrid();
}
```

The error is : **Input string was not in a correct format**

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What line is throwing the error? We'll need more details to help you. The only string that you have shown is your `cmdnew.CommandText`, and that looks fine with a cursory glance.

Comment: Use a parameterised query... ps Feedate is a really bad name for an integer...

Comment: Because you are not telling us, I'm going to assume it's `Convert.ToInt32(txtSearch.Text)` because you don't have a valid number in `txtSearch`.

Comment: This line-- grdFeeDetail.DataSource = BindStudentsearchList(Convert.ToInt32(txtSearch.Text), 0);

Comment: i want to search that student, which submitted Fee on Date..

Comment: So `FeeDate` is a `date` in our database? What is your input for `txtSearch`? And why cast it to an `int` if it is a `date`?

Comment: txtSearch.Text doesn't contain something that can be converted to an int32...

Answer (score 0):

```
grdFeeDetail.DataSource = BindStudentsearchList(Convert.ToInt32(txtSearch.Text), 0);
```

Convert.ToInt32 will throw a FormatException if the string is not parsable as an integer. You say that `txtSearch.Text` will contain a string representation of a date. That cannot be parsed as an integer.

If your DB column is a date, then FeeDate should be a `DateTime`, and you need to use [DateTime.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Convert.ToDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of Convert.ToInt32.

Your example input of "21/6/2014" looks like a correct date in most parts of the world. Since you're getting a FormatException with it, your machine may be set to a culture that does not recognize "dd/m/yyyy" as a valid date format. There are overloads of DateTime.Parse, DateTime.ParseExact, and Convert.ToDateTime that allow you to specify format or culture info.

Also, even though `FeeDate` is an integer and less vulnerable to SQL injection, it's still a good habit to use a parameterized query rather than concatenating strings:

```
            cmdnew.CommandText = "SELECT A.Studentid,A.Name,F.FeeDate,F.Fee FROM tbl_Student A inner join tbl_Fee F on A.StudentId= F.fkStudentId where FeeDate=@feeDate  and A.IsArcive=0";
            cmdnew.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@feeDate", FeeDate));
```

Comment: Then what do you think `Convert.ToInt32("21/6/2014")` is going to do? I've updated my answer based on this.

Comment: i tried it but also occure a error and i did tried convert.ToDatetime() then its time error is String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Updated answer based on this. What you have is a problem parsing a string as a date. It could be a problem with the CurrentCulture setting on your machine, but trying to turn it into an integer won't solve the problem.